# what is the limit of $\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{\left( \int_{0}^{x}{{{e}^{{{t}^{2}}}}dt} \right)}^{1/x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

I tired first to suppose that $I=\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{\left( \int_{0}^{x}{{{e}^{{{t}^{2}}}}dt} \right)}^{1/x}}$ then take both sides as $\ln$ to get ,

$\ln I =\underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\frac{1}{x}\ln\int_{0}^{x}{{{e}^{{{t}^{2}}}}dt}$

Can this road leads us to the solution or we need to use another shortcut!

Comment: I believe that you can then apply L'Hopital's rule (and the fundamental theorem of calculus) to get the limit, although I might be missing something.

Comment: You should correct your question. I assume you mean $x\to 0^+$?

Comment: This should not be that difficult if you notice that integral tends to $0$ and $1/x\to\infty $ so that the answer is $0$. Remember that the form $0^{\infty} $ is not indeterminate.

Answer (score 4):

Since $e^{t^2}$ is increasing you have $$0 < \int_0^x e^{t^2} \, dt < x e^{x^2}$$ and thus $$0 < \left( \int_0^x e^{t^2} \, dt \right)^{1/x}  < x^{1/x} e^x$$ for all $x > 0$. Since $\dfrac{\ln x}x \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0^+$ you find that $x^{1/x} \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$.  Now apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: (+1) This is the way I approached it.  I deleted my post after seeing your solution.  I hope that you are doing well and staying safe and healthy my friend.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), one can use the Sandwich theorem as follows:
$$\color{red}0 \le \color{blue}{\left(\int_0^x e^{t^2}\mathrm dt\right)^{1/x}}\le \left(\int_0^{\infty}e^{t^2}\mathrm dt\right)^{1/x} = \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)^{1/x}\to \color{red}0$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\color{blue}{\left(\int_0^x e^{t^2}\mathrm dt\right)^{1/x}} = \color{red}0$$

Answer (score 0):

As you showed,

$$\ln{I} = \lim_{x\to0}\Bigg(\frac{1}{x}\cdot\ln\bigg(\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}dt\bigg)\Bigg)$$

This allows you to deduce the limit immediately. The limit of $\frac{1}{x}$ as $x\to0^{+} $ is $\infty$. Meanwhile, the limit of $\ln{\int}$ is $-\infty$. Thus,

$$\ln{I} \to -\infty$$

as $x \to 0^+$.

$$\implies I \to 0$$

as $x \to 0^+$.